# jquery slide up and down with inner ul li and changing the up and down arrow corrspondingly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing issue of up/down arrow while sliding up and down inner `li` from outer `ul` using jquery.

I am able to change button icon on slide down but unable to change it on slide up.

Below is the html and js code :

```
<div class="container help-container" role="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-4 help-index">
                <div class="index-header">Index</div>
                <ul class="index-list sidebar-navigation">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span> Education
                        </a>
                        <ul class="index-sublist sidebar-inner-list">
                            <li class="active-index"><a href="#!">Glossary of Acronyms</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#!">Glossary of Terms</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria- hidden="true"></span>Index2
                        </a>
                        <ul class="index-sublist sidebar-inner-list">
                            <li><a href="#!">Index2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#!">Index2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria- hidden="true"></span>Index3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Index4
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.sidebar-inner-list > li').hide();
$('.sidebar-navigation > li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.sidebar-navigation > li').not(this).find('li').slideUp();
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-    right').
        addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $(this).find('.sidebar-inner-list li').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/gbhopale/pmz614x8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your script

```
$('.sidebar-navigation > li span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
```

so on every click it will change the arrows from bottom to right then will run your script and change the clickable only to bottom arrow .

You script:

```
$('.sidebar-inner-list > li').hide();

$('.sidebar-navigation > li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.sidebar-navigation > li span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
        $('.sidebar-navigation > li').not(this).find('li').slideUp();
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');

        $(this).find('.sidebar-inner-list li').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmz614x8/1/